# Error when importing Library in android

Tags: android, android-library

I am trying to implement Google Analytics in my android app for that I need to import one library. when I am trying to import that library it shows one error like

```
Could not write file: C:\Documents and Settings\ignite054\Desktop\i\Version                    
      4\Project\PashuPalan\.classpath.
C:\Documents and Settings\ignite054\Desktop\i\Version 4\Project\PashuPalan\.classpath   
(Access is denied)
```

How to solve this? please help me.

Comment: Please follow the instruction on this link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/

Answer (score 1):

First copy the jar file from the `android-sdk\extras\google\analytics_sdk_v2\libGoogleAnalytics.jar` and add it into your projects `libs` folder.

The try to add library `libGoogleAnalytics.jar` to build path (in `libs` right click on `libGoogleAnalytics.jar -> BuildPAth -> Add to Build Path`).

Do not add anything in Manifest file and in your java file use `Ctrl+Shift+O` to automatically organize your imports.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the directory and file is still there.
And, take a look that C:\Documents and Settings\ignite054\Desktop\i\Version
      4\Project\PashuPalan is a valid path, has a .classpath file and it is readable.
Maybe .classpath file is hidden, removing the hidden attribute may resolve the issue.